# How to switch login shell of remote server to bash for the duration of the session only?

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, tmux

The default login shell is zsh, but my setup is heavy on on functions and exporting them.
I don't want to port each function into its own file the way zsh requires.

I do the following when connecting to a remote server:

```
ssh user@host -t " \
somefunc() { somecommands; }; export -f somefunc; \
tmux (start new sessions...etc) "
```

This works well if the default shell is bash, but if zsh the functions don't get exported.

is there a way to switch the shell to bash for the duration of the remote session on all windows within tmux?

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to copy a script to the remote host, then execute the script with whatever shell you like. `scp yourScript user@host:; ssh user@host -t 'bash yourScript'`.

Comment: I tried that. This will open an ssh session locally. where I want it to get to the tmux code so it could open a tmux session instead.

Comment: why not save the functions in bashrc and configure tmux to use Bash?

Comment: It is a shared server I can’t play and change with its files.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are looking for, but tmux looks at the tmux option `default-shell` for the shell to use, or at `SHELL=` in the environment, so you can set one of those.

Comment: Notice that I am asking about the statements (before) using tmux. The main thing I am trying to do is define functions that would apply to all tmux panes. The above code I have works and for every new tmux pane I open over ssh the function (somefunc) will be defined. There is no way I could do that if for example the default shell on the remote host is zsh. Since they don't export functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from problems with quotes in your string you should be able to run `bash` from the start and so have it as your shell:

```
ssh user@host -t bash -c "' \
 somefunc() { somecommands; }; export -f somefunc; \
 SHELL=/bin/bash exec tmux (start new sessions...etc) '"
```

or experiment with `bash -i` or `-il`:

```
ssh user@host -t exec bash -c \''f(){ ...;};export -f f; SHELL=/bin/bash exec bash -i'\'
```

Comment: Didn't work. Still assumes zsh shell and none of the export functions work.

Comment: Try adding `SHELL=/bin/bash` (or wherever it is) before the `exec tmux`, or set the `default-shell` option in tmux.

Comment: I tried it on a raspian and it seemed ok. Make sure you don't already have a tmux server running on the remote, as it will have its own environment set.

Comment: Are you sure you had zsh as a default first on the remote host? Did the export take effect?

Comment: Yes, I created a new user and did `chsh -s /bin/zsh` for it, tried an ssh to check it was in zsh, then did the above ending `SHELL=/bin/bash exec tmux` and in the tmux window I got a bash shell and the function was found and ran ok. Perhaps there is something in your `.bashrc` or similar that is clearing the env.